# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a web application Reactjs and Redux, where you can login to dashboard and then you can logout.
I'm using "redux-react-session" to manage sessions, and i created an action called logoutUser in userActions.js. this action is imported and called in Dashboard.jsx where i added a logout button with onClick event. What i'm expecting is when i click on logout it should simply redirects me to home page ('/')

**My problem is**: Whenever i click on logout button, it redirects me to home page ('/') then refreshing back to dashboard.

Console.dev error:

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual
> type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store
> setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to
> handle dispatching functions.

userAction.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { sessionService } from 'redux-react-session'


export const loginUser = (credentials, navigate, setFieldError, setSubmitting) => {
    //make checks and get some data
    return () => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/form/signin",
            credentials,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            const { data } = response;

            if (data.status === "FAILED") {
                const { message } = data;

                //check for specific error
                if (message.includes("credentials")) {
                    setFieldError("email", message);
                    setFieldError("password", message);
                } else if (message.includes("password")) {
                    setFieldError("password", message);
                    alert("Wrong email or password")
                }
            } else if (data.status === "SUCCESS") {
                const userData = data.data;
                const token = userData._id;

                sessionService.saveSession(token)
                    .then(() => {
                        sessionService.saveUser(userData)
                            .then(() => {
                                if (userData.role === "admin") {
                                    navigate("/dashboard")
                                } else if (userData.role === "user") {
                                    navigate("/joblist")
                                } else {
                                    navigate("/")
                                    alert("Role is not known, please contact Admin or make a new account!")
                                    sessionService.deleteSession(token)
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(err => console.error(err))
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err))
            }
        })
            .catch(err => { console.error(err) });
    }
}




export const signupUser = (credentials, navigate, setFieldError, setSubmitting) => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/form/signup",
            credentials,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            const { data } = response;

            if (data.status === 'FAILED') {
                const { message } = data;
                //check for specific error
                if (message.includes("name")) {
                    setFieldError("name", message);
                } else if (message.includes("email")) {
                    setFieldError("email", message);
                } else if (message.includes("date")) {
                    setFieldError("dateOfBirth", message);
                } else if (message.includes("password")) {
                    setFieldError("password", message);
                }

                //complete submission
                setSubmitting(false);

            } else if (data.status === "SUCCESS") {
                //Login user after successfull signup
                const { email, password } = credentials;

                dispatch(loginUser({ email, password }, navigate, setFieldError, setSubmitting))
            }
        })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
}




export const logoutUser = (navigate) => {
    return () => {
        sessionService.deleteSession();
        sessionService.deleteUser();
        navigate('/');
    }
}
```

Dashboard.jsx:

```
import {
  StyledTitle,
  StyledSubTitle,
  Avatar,
  StyledButton,
  ButtonGroup,
  StyledFormArea,
  colors
} from './../../components/Styles';

//Formik
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import { TextInput } from '../../components/FormLib';

//Logo
import Logo from './../../assets/logo.png';

//auth & redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutUser } from '../../auth/actions/userActions';

//React router
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';




const Dashboard = ({ logoutUser }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Avatar image={Logo} />
      </div>
      <StyledFormArea bg={colors.dark2} style={{ marginLeft: '-400px' }}>
        <StyledTitle size={65}>Welcome to Dashboard </StyledTitle>
        <StyledSubTitle size={27}>Feel free to post new jobs</StyledSubTitle>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            title: '',
            description: ''
          }}
        >
          <Form>
            <TextInput
              name="title"
              type="text"
              label="Title :"
              placeholder="Job Title"
            />
            <TextInput
              name="description"
              type="text"
              label="Description :"
              placeholder="Job description"
            />
          </Form>
        </Formik>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <StyledButton to="#">Post Job</StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            bg={colors.red}
            to="#"
            onClick={()=> dispatch(logoutUser(navigate))}
          >
            Logout
          </StyledButton>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </StyledFormArea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null, { logoutUser })(Dashboard);
```

Store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

import {sessionService} from 'redux-react-session';

const initialState = {}
const middlewares = [thunk]

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
sessionService.initSessionService(store);

export default store;
```

**Edit:**

If i add `return()` in the action:

```
export const logoutUser = (navigate) => {
    return () => {
        sessionService.deleteSession();
        sessionService.deleteUser();
        navigate('/');
    }
}
```

I get this error in Console.dev:

```
Uncaught TypeError: logoutUser(...) is not a function
```

**Edit (2):**

Removing `return ( ) => {` ... `}` and `( )` of `logoutUser(navigate)( )` will keep the page refreshing then get me back to dashboard

Comment: I think you may have added too many parentheses in `logoutUser(navigate)()`.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Removing `( )` doesn't help, clicking on the button does nothing literally.

Comment: removing `return ( ) => {` ... `}` and `( )` of `logoutUser(navigate)( )` will keep the page refreshing then get me back to dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue is related to using both the `connect` Higher Order Component ***and*** manually dispatching actions to the store. The `connect` HOC automatically wraps the action creators in a call to `dispatch` and injects a dispatchable action as a prop into the decorated component. Your code is then wrapping `logoutUser` in another call to `dispatch`. Pick one or the other, but not both.

### Using `connect` HOC

```
//auth & redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutUser } from '../../auth/actions/userActions';

//React router
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const Dashboard = ({ logoutUser }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <StyledFormArea bg={colors.dark2} style={{ marginLeft: '-400px' }}>
        <StyledTitle size={65}>Welcome to Dashboard </StyledTitle>
        <StyledSubTitle size={27}>Feel free to post new jobs</StyledSubTitle>
        ...
        <ButtonGroup>
          <StyledButton to="/">Post Job</StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            bg={colors.red}
            to="/" // <-- fix target from "#" to "/"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent any default button actions
              logoutUser(navigate); // <-- call decorated action
            }}
          >
            Logout
          </StyledButton>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </StyledFormArea>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  logoutUser
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

### Using `useDispatch` hook

```
//auth & redux
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutUser } from '../../auth/actions/userActions';

//React router
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const Dashboard = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <StyledFormArea bg={colors.dark2} style={{ marginLeft: '-400px' }}>
        <StyledTitle size={65}>Welcome to Dashboard </StyledTitle>
        <StyledSubTitle size={27}>Feel free to post new jobs</StyledSubTitle>
        ...
        <ButtonGroup>
          <StyledButton to="/">Post Job</StyledButton>
          <StyledButton
            bg={colors.red}
            to="/" // <-- fix target from "#" to "/"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent any default button actions
              dispatch(logoutUser(navigate)); // <-- dispatch action
            }}
          >
            Logout
          </StyledButton>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </StyledFormArea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

The error message also seems to be saying that you haven't yet added any asynchronous action middleware to your redux store.

> You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle
> dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching
> functions.

I suggest following the `redux` and `react-redux` guides for adding this to your store configuration, or update to `redux-toolkit` (*same maintainers*) which includes the thunk middleware out-of-the-box since it is such a common use case.

Comment: Thank you so much but it seems like there's something missing, i tested both codes (once using `connect` and other using `dispatch`) but both codes lead to the same result, it seems like there's nothing happens upon clicking logout button at all (there no errors either). Also, i'm already using thunk Middleware, kindly check store.js code, i already updated my question.

Comment: @Michael Would it be possible to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code, just a basic example, that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-poitras-24g5l3  .I never forked any of my git repo before, i hope everything is fine and clear to you. Also you can check my problem here in this github link (if codesanbox isn't setup correctly) https://github.com/darkpsinight/Genext-IT_stage_Recruit_App

Comment: @Michael I can't run your backend code in the sandbox, but that isn't needed at this point. We only need to see a minimal front end with redux to test dispatching actions and navigating. Can you try to reduce the code in the sandbox down to a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Just change `to="#"` to `to="/"`
This fixed my problem along side with solution of @Drew Reese using `useDispatch` hook **OR** Using `connect` HOC.     (Please update your answer so i can accept it as solved answer.)

Comment: @Michael Ah, you know what, I saw that and wondered if I should ask about it. I've updated my answer to also include calling `preventDefault` on the `onClick` event object to prevent any default button click actions. Is the `to` prop even necessary there?

Comment: To be honnest, `to="/"`  doesn't look necessary for me while i already used `navigate('/')` and it should do the job. I tried to remove it but i got a blanc page immediately !!

Comment: if you got any better suggestion , it would be nice for us to learn :)

Comment: @Michael Unless that `StyledButton` is doing something specific with that `to` prop I think it can be removed (*if it's not a required props*). The reason using a `navigate('/')` didn't work is because it's an imperative navigation action; you are telling `react-router-dom` to navigate immediately, right then and there.